# Does nitrogen pressure in tyres fluctuate to much a lower degree than air with changes in temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, vapor-pressure

This is my first question in this site. I am referring to this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/is-there-a-way-to-fill-your-tires-with-nitrogen).The linked question what is the advantage of filling nitrogen in bike tubes over air and I got some answers such as:

> *The biggest advantage to filling your tires with Nitrogen is consistency.*
>
> *Air pressure fluctuates based on temperature, whereas Nitrogen fluctuates to a much much lower degree*

and

> *Nitrogen changes pressure with temperature slightly less than water does*

But I want to know the reason. Please help me understand this scientifically.

Comment: I've tidied up your formatting and grammar and subtly changed the title so is poses the question rather than assuming the answer. I hope I haven't blurred your intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be no scientific explanation, because the argument itself is incorrect.

For the most part *air* is *nitrogen*.  To be specific, about 80% of dry air is made up from nitrogen.  In fact both nitrogen and oxygen, the second major components of air that takes up almost all the other 20%, behave extremely like ideal gas.   Pressures of **dry air** and **pure nitrogen gas** at different temperatures, from far below freezing point to above boiling point, have indeed been measured to incredibly high accuracy.  **The difference between these two gases is below 0.1%.**   In fact, near room temperature, many types of gas are close to ideal gas and have very similar temperature profiles.

I am not sure why people are comparing nitrogen with water in that question thread you mentioned.  Water is a minor component of air and its concentration varies so dramatically across places.  However, even in a summer day, at the maximum humidity of 100%, the amount of water in the air is only 10% of that of oxygen.

Basically, **pressure of nitrogen gas do not fluctuate less with change of temperature compared to normal air**.